# Reverse populate in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can i reverse populate in mongo. I have 2 schema's

User:

```
var user_scheme = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  age:Number,
  roles:{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Role'
  }
 });
```

Role:

```
var role_scheme = new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
});
```

Documents:

```
///user
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5bf9a19b01ce3e19b440aed8"),
"name" : "user1",
"age" : 22,
"roles" : ObjectId("5c0242621ab7b677e6b2e01e"),
"__v" : 0
}
 ///role
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c0242621ab7b677e6b2e01e"),
"name" : "Admin"
}
```

Code:

```
User.find().populate('roles').exec(function (err, data) {
 res.json(data);
})
```

Here i can get roles under user, But how i get users under each role.

Comment: Please post the sample collections

Comment: Ques updated...

Comment: Post the documents from the `roles` collection as well. And with which `role` you want to find the user?

Comment: Now how can i get user1 inside Admin role ,for example-- Role.find().populate('users') something like that..

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use below [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation

```
Role.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "name" : "Admin" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "roleId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$roles", "$$roleId"] } } }
    ],
    "as": "users"
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 11):

The `$lookup` function by @Ashh was not working for me.

I used a more recent version :

```js
$lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'organization',
    as: 'users'
}
```

Comment: The best & the easiest answer possible and without any external module . Should be the approved answer

Comment: @Ashh's answer is not working for you because it is for arrays. User has **roles** field!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`mongoose-reverse-populate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-reverse-populate)  module.