# How to query two Collections and return one response?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get the result of movies + the average rating for each movie.
The information lays in two different collections. The rating collection holds the movie ID.

Movies - the main collection

```
[
    {
        name: "The Matrix"
        genres: [
            "5e80bc463c410a7291dee8c1",
            "5e80bc463c410a7291dee8c2"
        ],
    },
    {
        name: "The Matrix 2"
        genres: [
            "5e80bc463c410a7291dee8c1",
            "5e80bc463c410a7291dee8c2"
        ],
    }
]
```

Ratings

```
[
    {
        movie: "5e3355c206c7cd030e48b8bc",
        user: "5e3355c206c7cd030e48b8b4",
        rating: 10
    },
    {
        movie: "5e3355c206c7cd030e48b34c",
        user: "5e3355c206c7cd030e48b544",
        rating: 7
    },
    {
        movie: "5e3355c206c7cd030e4823bc",
        user: "5e3355c206c7cd03344823bc",
        rating: 5
    }
}
```

I want the following result:

```
{
    "total": 1,
    "page": 0,
    "perPage": 25,
    "pageSize": 1,
    "movies": [
        {
            _id: "5e3b0e57870c15002e29a238",
            name: 'The Matrix',
            genres: ['Action', 'Sci-Fi'],
            rating: 10
        },
        {
            _id: "5e3b0e57870c15002e29a239",
            name: 'The Matrix 2',
            genres: ['Action', 'Sci-Fi'],
            rating: 10
        },
    ]
}
```

I don't understand how to add the average rating for each movie into the query result.
My current query looks like this:

```
Movie.find(demand)
    .select("name genres")
    .skip(page * limit)
    .limit(limit)
    .populate('genres', ['name'])
    .lean()
    .exec((err, movies) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }

        Movie.countDocuments(demand).exec((count_error, count) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json(count_error);
            }
            return res.status(200).json({
                total: count,
                page: page,
                perPage: limit,
                pageSize: movies.length,
                movies: movies
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongoose terms, you are looking for "reverse populate", which (as far as I know) does not come with mongoose out of the box. (See e.g. [Reverse populate in mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53570645/reverse-populate-in-mongoose)).

Instead what you can do is make an aggregate mongo query, like so:

```
Movie.aggregate([{
    $match: demand
}, {
    $skip: page * limit
}, {
    $limit: limit
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: "ratings",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "movie",
        as: "ratings"
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        name: 1,
        genres: 1,
        ratting: {$avg: "$ratings.rating"}
    }
}]).exec((err, movies) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.json(err);
    }
    Genre.populate(movies, {path: 'genres', select: 'name'}, (err, movies) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(err);
        }
        // rest of your code to count etc.
    });
});
```

Comment: Well that worked immediately. The reverse populate works even out of the box. Thank you sir